# Issue with js function to multiply price by quantity

Tags: javascript

I'm displaying a quick order form on my product pages with fields such as quantity and line total.
The quantity can be adjusted using plus/minus buttons. 
This is the code

```
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Size</p>
        <p>SKU</p>
      </td>
      <td class="right-column">
          <p>{{ variant.title | escape}}</p>
          <input type="hidden"  value="{{ variant.id }}" id="variant-{{ forloop.index0 }}"/>
          <p>{{ variant.sku | escape}}</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Quantity</p>
      </td>
      <td >
        <div class="cart-quantity">
       <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity-2-{{ forloop.index0 }}' id="quantity-minus-{{ forloop.index0 }}" />
       <input type="number" name="updates[]" id="quantity-2-{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="quantity qty-input totalqty-2" value="0" />
       <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity-2-{{ forloop.index0 }}' id="quantity-plus-{{ forloop.index0 }}" />
   </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="last-mobile-row">
      <td>
        <p>Unit price</p>
        <p>Line total</p>
      </td>
      <td class="right-column">
        <p>{{ variant.price | money }}</p>
          <span>£</span><p id="line_price_2{{ variant.id }}" class="total-price total-price-2">0.00</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

The function for the plus/minus buttons looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// This button will increment the value
$('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        // Increment
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});
// This button will decrement the value till 0
$(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        // Decrement one
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});
});
```

And the code to update the line total:

```
$("input#quantity-plus-{{ forloop.index0 }}").bind("click", function() {
  var toAdd = new Array();
      var qty ;
    toAdd.push({
      quantity_id: $("#quantity-2-{{ forloop.index0 }}").val() || 0
    });

  var request_{{ variant.id }} = toAdd.shift();
  var tempQty_{{ variant.id }} = request_{{ variant.id }}.quantity_id;
  var price_{{ variant.id }} = {{ variant.price }}
  var newNo_{{ variant.id }} = tempQty_{{ variant.id }}  * price_{{ variant.id }};
  var newNo2_{{ variant.id }} = Math.floor(newNo_{{ variant.id }}) / 100
  $('#line_price_2{{ variant.id }}').html(newNo2_{{ variant.id }}.toFixed(2));

  var sum = 1;
  $('.totalqty-2').each(function(){
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
        $('.totalqty_display').html(sum);
  });
});
```

However, when the plus button is clicked the first time it doesn't change the line total price, on the second click it works but then only adds the price of one, even though the quantity is 2. 
I had the same issue with the quantity which is why I added `var sum = 1;`. This made it work correctly. So my assumption is that the first value that's being pulled through is 0 rather than 1 after the plus button has been clicked, even though it shows 1 in the quantity field.

Not sure how to fix this though, any suggestion are appreciated!

Comment: The `<input value='+'>` in your html seems odd for an element that I think you are trying to use for integer increments. You might want to take a closer look at that.